# Edit log4j2 composite configuration via JMX

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, jmx, jconsole

- I am trying to change log levels, as well as add/remove loggers from an app we have without editing it's code/changing the multiple log4j configs it has.
- I am able to do all these steps for applications with single log4j config xml
- But for apps with multiple configurations, I am not able to retrieve the composite configuration via JMX (it just shows blank, I am just able to change levels for configured loggers, I also want to add new loggers/remove them), and hence cannot edit it.
- Is there any way I can retrieve the config for such scenario using JMX? (Or any better alternative?)
- Sharing some images:

1. output of getConfigText operation in jconsole for a project with multiple log4j configs
   [image: Here is the output of getConfigText operation in jconsole for a project with multiple log4j configs]
2. for a project with single log4j config

[image: This one for a project with single log4j config]